# how to run pl/sql program in oracle sql developer

Tags: plsql, output, oracle-sqldeveloper

```
DECLARE
   message  varchar2(20):= 'Hello, World!';
BEGIN
   dbms_output.put_line(message);
END;
```

How can I execute above pl/sql program in Oracle SQL Developer.
Can any one suggest me?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

I have tried following the steps shown in this image.  Some steps are excluded but I am sure you will understand when you encounter them.
[image: screenshot]

Comment: thanq.but in my SQL developer there is no dbms output

Answer (score 21):

If you do not see DBMS output just add

```
set serveroutput on
```

at the top and execute the statements as a script, you will see the output in "Script output" section.

```
set serveroutput on
DECLARE
message  varchar2(20):= 'Hello, World!';
BEGIN
dbms_output.put_line(message);
END;
```

Answer (score 5):

Assuming you already have a connection configured in SQL Developer:

- from the `View` menu, select `DBMS Output`
- in the DBMS Output window, click the green `plus` icon, and select your connection
- right-click the connection and choose `SQL worksheet`
- paste your query into the worksheet
- run the query

Comment: can u suggest me please how to configure SQl Developer for writing and executing  PL/SQL programs

Comment: in view menu there is no DBMS Output option please tel me

Comment: Which version of SQL/Developer are you using? Which language settings? (in my (German) IDE, it's called "DBMS Ausgabe" instead of "Dbms output"))

Comment: am using 11g version.i select English language

Comment: Frank use ver 4.0 http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/developer-tools/sql-developer/overview/index.html

Answer (score 2):

First execute  'set serveroutput on' query in worksheet then check in View menu, DBMS output option will appear.

Answer (score 0):

Surround your procedure code accordingly :

```
create or replace procedure YOUR_TEST as
begin
  <proc code here>
end;
/
show errors
```

Hit the green arrow to compile - you should get the following message :

```
Procedure YOUR_TEST compiled
```

Now run it :

```
exec YOUR_TEST ;
```

n.b.:  env:  Oracle 12g, Sql Developer v18.4